# Not able to pass a variable to php function

Tags: php, function, global

I know this has been asked in various ways here, but I think I must be simply stupid!

I have this incredibly simple function:

```
$firstline = "please say";

function localSidebarText() {
global $firstline;

echo $firstline;
echo "hello";

}

localSidebarText();
```

However, it is outputting the word Hello, but not the "please say" before it.

What incredibly obvious thing am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not passing anything to the function. You're also not declaring `$firstline` as global inside your function.

Comment: Okay, typo there - I was simplifying down from the real function and forgot to change a variable name - I have edited it, but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: @Gurubear now it does work, check if you're saving it, if you're opening the right file, if you're refreshing the cache (ctrl+F5 in FF).

Comment: I am even hitting it with a hammer ... maybe I need a bigger one! Something must be working because the Hello gets printed, just not the variable.

Comment: @GuruBear: The code snippet you posted works: `please sayhello`. You have a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using global variables. "Passing" something to a function is simple:

```
function localSidebarText($pageTitle, $firstLine) {
  echo $firstLine;
  echo "hello";
}

localSidebarText("Some page title", "The first line");
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I am beginning to think I have something strange elsewhere which is stopping this working...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not in the function scope and so is undefined in the function itself. You could replace:

```
global $pagetitle;
```

with:

```
global $pagetitle, $firstline;
```

or put the variable inside the function OR last but not least give the function the variable as argument.

Comment: Yeah, did a typo - but the corrected version does not work either

Comment: i just tried it and its working.

    <?php 

    $firstline = "please say";

    function localSidebarText() {
    global $firstline, $pagetitle;

    echo $firstline;
    echo "hello";

    }

    localSidebarText();

Comment: okay, then I have something strange going on elsewhere!

Answer (score -1):

```
global $firstline = "please say";
global $pagetitle;
function localSidebarText() {
echo $firstline;
echo "hello";
}

localSidebarText();
```

OR

```
global $pagetitle;
function localSidebarText($textToPrint) {
echo $textToPrint;
echo "hello";
}

localSidebarText("please say");
```